# Direct image uploading service folder

Tags: android, image-uploading

I have a folder on my service

my pasta:

> http:// myip:port/project/images

is to upload images forncecidas by user direct to the folder? or have to use webservice? Does anyone know any solution or example?

Comment: android send the image to a folder on the server

Comment: If you read 20 pages on this forum with tags android and asynctask you will find many examples of uploading a file to a server. Now start reading.